# Calculate average value over multiple years for each hour and day

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate an average over multiple years for hourly data. I want to retain the days and hours and average over the years. I feel like this should be simple but I have looked around for an answer and not found one.

I am using R version 3.0.3.

```
start <- ISOdatetime(1970, 1, 1, hour=0, min=0, sec=0, tz="GMT")
end <- ISOdatetime(1971, 12, 31, hour=18, min=0, sec=0, tz="GMT")
set.seed(1)
z <- zooreg(rnorm(2920), start = start , end = end, frequency = 4, deltat = 21600)

#attempt to aggregate ... doesn't work
z.daily.agg <- aggregate(z, as.POSIXct(cut(time(z), "6 hours", include=T)), mean)
```

What I would like for the output is the following:

01-01 00:00 average of all January 1st zero hours from 1970-1971

01-01 06:00 average of all January 6th zero hours from 1970-1971

Thanks for your assistance with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will work - using the hour function from the lubridate package.

```
require(lubridate)
aggregate(z, hour(index(z)), mean)
```

Edit in response to your comments - sorry, I didn't realise exactly what you wanted. You can average across each hour by day by month across the two years (which I think is what you want) like so:

```
aggregate(z ~ month(index(z)) + day(index(z)) + hour(index(z)), FUN = 'mean')
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This seems like a simple and good approach. However, when I ran hour(index(z)) I got 'could not find function "hour"'. Was that from a different package?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I think there was something up with my lubridate install. I still wanted to retain the days and hours in my average. This result only gives the average of the hours. Is there a way to do this with lubridate?

Comment: Edited my answer to be more what you wanted. If you don't care about the months and just want days of the month (1-31) you can just take out the month term.

Answer (score 0):

A little crude but you could

```
#1) Use the substr function to extract the parts of the date string you want:

    date = substr(time(z), 6,16)

#2) Then bind this to the data:

    temp = data.frame(z, date)

#3) Make sure the date is a factor:

    temp$date = as.factor(temp$date)

#4) And now aggregate:

    aggregate(temp$z~temp$date, FUN=mean)
```

Does this give you the results you were after?